# Insert into a table values that are in another table matching condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables `(AllProducts)` and `(Categories)`, some product can have more than one category so I have used a 3rd table `(Product_Category)` to deal with this many-to-many relation.

During my first design of the database I created a table for each category and populated them with the products name (product name is unique).

Now, I am trying to insert the data that are in the categories tables I created earlier  into the new table `(Product_Category)` so I wrote a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Product_Category(prodID,categoryID)
  SELECT
    (SELECT ID FROM AllProducts 
     WHERE ProductName IN(SELECT Products FROM Poltries))
   ,(SELECT 1)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I understand why I am getting the error but I don't know how to write it.

What I want is:

Select the ID of every product from `(AllProducts)` table that its name is in `Category_A table` (in this example 'Polteries') then insert this value into the `column [prodID]` and then insert a constant value `(category ID)` into the column `[categoryID]`.

---

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Product_Category(prodID,categoryID)
SELECT ID, 1
FROM AllProducts 
WHERE ProductName IN (SELECT Products FROM Poltries)
```